# Does sbt dist compile the code or just copies files from target directory

Tags: playframework-2.6

I have a `Play Framework`/`Scala` application. I want to make a production version of the application. I want do `dockerise` the application

If I run `sbt dist` to create production version of my application, would `sbt` compile and build the code and also include application specific files (eg. `logback.xml` and `application.conf`) in the package or does it just pick all files from `target` folder and convert them into a `zip` file?

I am wondering if I need to copy the configuration and logging files explicitly in `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 0):

So I have found that (a) sbt dist does compile the code. Also my main problem was that my sbt task to create a deployable version of my application wasn't working. I had written an sbt task in build.sbt

```
lazy val `create-deployable` = taskKey[Unit]("create dist for deployment")
`create-deployable` := {
  implicit val root = baseDirectory.value
  if (createDist != 0) { println(s"got error ${createDist}");throw new Exception("Couldn't create dist. failed!")}
}

def createDist(implicit dir: File): Int = runScript("dist")
```

But when I would run it, I would get error `dist` not found. I changed it to `sbt dist` but then the error would be `sbt` not found. The issue was that the run the script, I was using `cmd /c` and the cmd console couldn't find sbt installed on my laptop.

The correct way to run sbt tasks is to (1) create an sbt task from Edit Configurations (2) give it a name (3) check that use sbt shell option is checked (4) give the task name which sbt recognises.

Eg.

[image]